# why linux cloned VM has not assigned IP from original VM network profil?

Tags: vmware-esxi

Using VC7.
Any idea why cloned linux VM after start has no IP assigned ?
Only solution is use customize OS during Clone....
As I understood "Clone VM" should copy whole VM.
FYI: original VM was powered off, so no IP conflict there, and new VM eth link was UP.
And original VM used static IP

Comment: What distribution are you running in your VM? Network interface configurations are often tied to the interface MAC address, so if the cloned VM has a new MAC (which it should), the system may not apply the static interface configuration.

Comment: I am using RH7.9

Comment: Take a look at the interface configuration file (something like  `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`). Look for a `HWADDR=` line. If you delete this (or modify it to match the local MAC) the interface configuration should apply correctly.

Comment: ok, I see that MAC is different when I used just clone VM... but why ? why is not copied this info from /etc ?  it is generated randomly during boot or ?

Comment: The interface MAC addresses are generated by your hypervisor when it creates a virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks. so pls feel free to mark this as answer :)